Как вытащить значение id с помощью цикла for?
Есть карточки товара, необходимо вывести значение id с помощью цикла For.
Вот что у меня получается:
 function setId() {
    const cardId = document.querySelectorAll(".rating__items");


    for (let index = 0; index < cardId.length; index++) {
      const cardIndex = cardId[index];
      console.log(cardIndex);
    }
  }
  setId();



https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute

Спасибо! Но я вытащу только конкретное указанное значение атрибута .. а как мне вытащить любое id из перебора?

function setId() {
  const cardId = document.querySelectorAll(".rating__items");

  for (let index = 0; index < cardId.length; index++) {
    const cardIndex = cardId[index];
    const idValue = cardIndex.id;
    console.log(idValue);
  }
}
setId();

Или
function setId() {
  const cardId = document.querySelectorAll(".rating__items");

  for (let index = 0; index < cardId.length; index++) {
    const cardIndex = cardId[index];
    const idValue = cardIndex.getAttribute("id");
    console.log(idValue);
  }
}
setId();


СПАСИБО ОГРОМНОЕ!!!

@YanaVozniuk, если мой ответ помог вам, пожалуйста, не забудьте отметить решением

Вроде отметила)) Спасибо еще раз)))

@YanaVozniuk, вы только проголосовали За, но не отметили решением

Отметила ка решение)

@YanaVozniuk, благодарен
